# Eclipse System.geProperty Windows7

Tags: java, eclipse

I am baffled....
I am using jdk1.6.0_24, Eclipse 3.6.2 on Windows7. Everything is 64bit.
The problem I am having is, the property (such as -Dmyki=helloDumbo) that I pass from Eclipse via the Run->Run Configuration->Arguments does not seems to get passed to my program.

As an example I have the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = System.getProperty("myki");
    System.out.println("myki = " + s);
    System.out.println("Arg = " + args[0]);
}
```

And my output is:

```
myki = null
Arg = -Dmyki=helloDumbo
```

From the above it seems that Eclipse passed down the arguments I put into the JVM but why System.getProperty() returned null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you put it in as a `VM argument` not a `Program argument`:

[image: SystemProperty Argument]

Comment: Thanks very much for this pointer, it makes me want to go back to my mum's tummy - sooo..... embarassing.